# Should my team use separate component libraries for mobile and web or a unified cross-platform one for both?

Tags: reactjs, components, libraries, styled-components

I am not sure whether to use separate React component libraries one for mobile and one for web or whether to create a unified one with styled components and react native web.

I wanted to know what have your experiences be in mixing both together or separating each? Pros/Cons, any issues you faced down the line? What do you recommend and why? Cannot seem to find a consensus on that, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

While mobile cross-platform solutions are pretty mature and stable now, especially React Native, solutions for unifying mobile and web are still more in under construction mode and you find fewer cases for the [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) for example.

**The general rule is that the more custom and non-standard app you build the more specific tools you need.** So I would definitely ask myself these 3 questions before making a decision:

- Is web functionality the same as mobile one? The more they are similar, the more plausible the option for one codebase for all of them,
- How many native modules, or web specific features do you need to have in the app? The fewer the better. Let's say you need to create some magic with CSS, but hey, there are [no CSS in React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style) and some properties you need might be missing,
- How much animation do you need to include? The less the better. Animations are done in an inherently different way on mobile and web, hence the less libraries that fills that gap.

When it comes to using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) for Reactjs and React Native you can reuse the components to some extent. You won't find `div` on React Native side and get `View` instead.

You can also consider using [Expo](https://expo.io/) for mobile apps to make the development and deployment easier, just check out [this page first](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo/).